# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_copyright_black_24dp.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f0d0007

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-resources, file-not-found

Hi all I am making a about us page in my android app with the help of gitLibaray.

[this is the library i m using](https://github.com/medyo/android-about-page)

The code works fine but the issue is when i am trying to show the copyright logo it gives me error i have add the stack track below.
Please check my code and correct me ..

**About.java**

```
     public class About extends Fragment {


    public About() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        String  desc = "CINEMATOGRAPHER AND PHOTOGRAPHER";

        Element versionElement = new Element();
        versionElement.setTitle("Version 1.0");

        View aboutPage = new AboutPage(getActivity())
                .isRTL(false)
                .setDescription(desc)
                .setImage(R.mipmap.jdlogo_circle)
                .addItem(versionElement)
                .addGroup("Connect with us")
                .addEmail("JDstudio.in@gmail.com")
                .addFacebook("facebook.com/JDstudio.in")
                .addYoutube("UC1DbBH3re7wceuz0XdCOJ8Q")
                .addInstagram("_jdstudio")
                .addItem(getCopyRightsElement())
                .create();

        return aboutPage;
    }

    Element getCopyRightsElement() {
        Element copyRightsElement = new Element();
        final String copyrights = String.format(getString(R.string.copy_right), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
        copyRightsElement.setTitle(copyrights);
        copyRightsElement.setIconDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_copyright_black_24dp);
        copyRightsElement.setIconTint(mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.R.color.about_item_icon_color);
        copyRightsElement.setIconNightTint(android.R.color.white);
        copyRightsElement.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        return copyRightsElement;
    }

}
```

**fragment_about.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.About">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**stack track**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.lenovo.jdstudio, PID: 7627
                  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_copyright_black_24dp.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f0d0007
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2430)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2385)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:998)
                      at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:562)
                      at mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.AboutPage.createItem(AboutPage.java:563)
                      at mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.AboutPage.addItem(AboutPage.java:407)
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.About.onCreateView(About.java:51)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file
                      at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
                      at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:501)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2412)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2385) 
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:998) 
                      at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.create(VectorDrawableCompat.java:562) 
                      at mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.AboutPage.createItem(AboutPage.java:563) 
                      at mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.AboutPage.addItem(AboutPage.java:407) 
                      at com.example.lenovo.jdstudio.About.onCreateView(About.java:51) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245) 
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image: copyright png in mipmap folder]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your .png in drawable folder and try.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: yeah did but getting the same thing again and again for the time being i have commented that line and app is running

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file`, is it a correct image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unicode` for copyright symbol in `string.xml` like this :-

```
<string name= "copy_right">&#169; your_String </string>
```

then mention here in your code :-

```
            Element getCopyRightsElement() {
            Element copyRightsElement = new Element();
            final String copyrights = String.format(getString(R.string.copy_right), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
            copyRightsElement.setTitle(copyrights);
            copyRightsElement.setIconTint(mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.R.color.about_item_icon_color);
            copyRightsElement.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            return copyRightsElement;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_copyright_black_24dp.png from xml type xml resource ID #0x7f0d0007
```

Above error message clearly states that **ic_copyright_black_24dp.png** image is not found in your res/mipmap folder check the folder if the file exists or not

Comment: image is not readable thats why its showing in red. delete and copy it back and try..